# react-router not working on production build in LAMP

Tags: reactjs, react-router, lamp

Hey has anyone experienced issues with react-router on a production build. I'm running a LAMP server and I've built my project put it in the http folder and when I go to a page I get `Object not found!`. I have setup react-router to go to certain pages based on certain conditions if I go to the root of the server i.e. `localhost/` it loads the main page but then if I click on links it works fine as soon as you try and manually go to a link by typing in the search box I get the error message `Object not found`
This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your server to return `index.html` if file not found (404).

Example:
Let's say you have `/users` route the will show your users list.
It will be ok if first you'll go to `/` (which will return `index.html` by default) and then click some router link and it will redirect you to that page. It will work because you wont make any additional requests to the server.
But if you go to `/users` first - you'll request it from the server. In that case server will try to find `users` file and it will not be there.

If this configuration is not possible consider using [hash router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter). The url will look like this `/#/users`

Comment: ok so how do I how configure the server to return index.html if file not found? I thought I had done that already?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with apache configuration. But it seems you need to add `Redirect 404 /index.html` somewhere. Maybe this link will help: https://serverfault.com/questions/303270/apache-redirect-404-and-errordocument-404-difference